# Reading and writing files in order - Python

Tags: python

Sorry Quite new to python as a language.

So I have 5 files lets say. item1.txt, item2.txt, item3.txt, item4.txt and item5.txt.
I am trying to call on the directory so that it picks out the first file (item1.txt) and print its content, then when I call on that function again (item2.txt) and its content within the file is printed... then (item3.txt) and then (item4.txt).

The order is important and the system must know what file has been printed so that the next file in line can print after the first eg. the content of item1.txt prints first then item2.txt.

Trying to use:

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + infile
```

But the problem is the directory needs to be added and the system needs to know what file and its content was printed before it.

Sorry if this was confusing.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you search for?

```
import glob
path = "path/to/your/txt/files/"
for infile in sorted(glob.glob(path + '*.txt')):
    print("Current File Being Processed is: " + path + infile)
```

Comment: Probably not. It's searching for files names `files*.txt` in the relative path `path/to/your/txt`, and, if it finds any, it will print out `path/to/your/txt/filesfilesfoo.txt`. And this is exactly what you use `os.path` instead of string functions—because it's impossible to create silly errors like the two you created here.

Comment: @abarnert: This was a type and yeah, os.path might be better. Edited my answer.

Comment: That's my point: The fact that you used code that causes big, and sometimes hard-to-debug, problems if you make the same kind of simple typo we all make all the time is much more important than the fact that you happened to make sure a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.path.join if you need to know the full path.

For example, a script that searches for all files in the current directory would look like this:

```
import os
import os.path
import re


# look for all files in current working directory, including subdirs
for (root, folders, files) in os.walk(os.getcwd()):    
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(fullpath)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Showing `os.path.join` is nice, but I think adding `os.walk` is going to confuse things for a novice who was happy with `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is the directory needs to be added…

To do this, use the methods in [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

You can do `pwd = os.getcwd()` to get the current working directory (the same directory that `glob('*.txt')` is searching), and then us `os.path.join(pwd, infile)`. But for the special case when you just have a path that's relative to the current directory, what you probably want is `os.path.abspath`. So:

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    inpath = os.path.abspath(infile)
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + inpath
```

> and the system needs to know what file and its content was printed before it.

To get the content of a file, you have to [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) it, then [`read`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) from it, like this:

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    inpath = os.path.abspath(infile)
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + inpath
    with open(inpath) as infileobj:
        contents = infileobj.read()
    print contents
```

Often, you don't really want to read the whole file into one big string, you just want to do some work on each line in the file. For that, you can just use a `for` statement, the same way you did with the list of strings that came back from `sorted`, to treat the file as a bunch of lines:

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    inpath = os.path.abspath(infile)
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + inpath
    with open(inpath) as infileobj:
        for line in infileobj:
            print line.rstrip('\n')
```

(The `rstrip('\n')` is because each line ends with a newline, but `print` adds its own newline, and you don't want a blank line between each line of the file.)

The advantage of this is that you don't have to read the whole file into memory to print it out. Not such a big deal if you're working on tiny files, but it makes a huge difference with bigger files.